# display cxSchedulerHolidays editor from application

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I have linked cxDateNavigator1 - cxSchedulerStorage1 - cxSchedulerHolidays1.
When you click cxSchedulerHolidays1 (at design time) it pops up the internal holidays editor which you can use to add holidays.

However, I cant figure out how to pop up this editor from within the running application like example on button click.

Searched devexpress database but could not find an answer. Their help is very difficult to navigate as they have the habit of bouncing you from question to question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually very simple to do.  The cxScheduler comes with a number of dialogs, in the cxSchedulerDialogs unit, including the one that the Scheduler's design-time support uses to pop up the `Holidays editor`.  The following works for me

```
uses
  [...], cxSchedulerDialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    cxDateNavigator1: TcxDateNavigator;
    cxSchedulerHolidays1: TcxSchedulerHolidays;
    cxSchedulerStorage1: TcxSchedulerStorage;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

[...]

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if cxShowHolidaysEditor(cxSchedulerHolidays1, cxDateNavigator1.LookAndFeel) then;
end;
```

if you need more help on this take a look at the HolidaysDemo.Dpr demo under
DevExpress VCL\ExpressScheduler\Demos\Delphi\HolidaysDemo